How to find the edge of an image in a PictureBox?
I have a multiple files that get Painted onto a picturebox by a third-party function that I can't hack into in any way. The function fits the image in vertically and aligns it to the left. Since the proportions of the files vary widely and I'm not sure how to get them ahead of time (these are .ema files), this results in empty space. I later save these files as .png. I would love to be able to determine where the drawing ends so that I could only save that portion. How could this be done? Thanks:)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548962/crop-remove-unwanted-space-at-the-edges-of-image

@dr.null thanks, that was really helpful!
