# How to resize images for iPhone and Android resolutions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image-processing

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application. I have a controller that I use to upload certain image files. The images have to match all Android and iPhone devices.

Are there any preexisting third-party dlls for this kind of task? I haven't written any code except the upload file action.

- I thought there maybe something automatically, so instead of cropping image inside web app, it's done automatically.

Comment: Define match. What size/quality an image is resized to is context dependent.

Comment: As i have said to all resolutions of mobile devices (iPhone and Android)

Comment: Does this SO answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357173/which-free-image-resizing-library-can-i-use-for-resizing-and-probably-serving-im

Comment: You might want to describe your image workflow a bit more as I'm still not sure how the images relate to the mobile device. Is it a mobile  specific web app or does it display in a desktop web app. Where are the images from (mobile or pc). Do you care about retina display/high density Android screens?

Comment: @Morrison Chang i will try to explain, for example you upload image to web site cms, i need to display the same image inside many mobile devices without spoil the quality and no cropping. The question is maybe some else did it automatically, if not never mind i will write it my self.

Comment: You could use css3 scale transform in your web-app to handle the sizes but at the possible cost of bandwidth, but otherwise you'll need to try out what image resizing work for the devices you are supporting. I would start with iOS devices to see if the app works well and then look at Android due to the much large number of screen sizes/densities available. The original iPhone is 320x480 but the latest Android is 1080x1920, so what would fill on some wont on other. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks you anyway, i know about all the resolutions, and i know about densities, i just wanted to compensate some time for me.
Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

is it important to resize the images in your application itself? Else I would suggest http://www.imagemagick.org/, which is maybe to powerfull. But is well known and realy popular in the web-developing world...

Hope I could help